# How to initialize multidimentional array in C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, variable-length-array

I am getting error when i am running this code

```
int row1=2,col1=2;

int mat1[row1][col1]=
{
    {1,5},
    {4,6}
};
```

What is wrong with this code??

**IDE: CodeBlocks**

> error: variable-sized object may not be initialized|

Comment: The error tells it all.

Comment: The error says it all.  You are trying to make a two-dimensional Variable-Length Array and send it an initializer.  Since it is a VLA, it's dimensions are unknown at compile-time, so how can you give it an initializer of fixed dimensions?

Comment: I'm confused why you need a variable sized array with a fixed size initialiser.  That doesn't really make sense.  Do you want arrays of different sizes at runtime?

Comment: I wonder how **this** gets upvoted? You really can't be any more specific in an error message ...

Comment: Simple fix: `const int init_mat [2][2] = { {1,5}, {4,6} }; memcpy(mat1, init_mat, sizeof init_mat);`

Comment: @Lundin What does the `memcpy` buy you, *especially* if the dimensions might actually need to change?

Comment: @DanielH It buys me the fastest possible way to initialize a VLA? Please note that `const int init_mat [2][2]` could be a local scope variable and could be changed accordingly. Perhaps I should have written `{ const int init_mat[MAX_X][MAX_Y] = { parameters }; ...`.

Comment: what is row2 and col2, its an unused variable?

Comment: @Lundin If the result is a VLA where the lengths are actually runtime variable (unlike in this example), then `memcpy` will put the numbers in the wrong cells. If not, then it's better to just make it a fixed-length array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per C specs, an array defined like

```
int mat1[row1][col1]=
{
    {1,5},
    {4,6}
};
```

is a **[VLA (Variable Length Array)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)** and cannot be initialized.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.2/P4,

> [...] If the size is an integer constant expression
>   and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length
>   array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

and chapter §6.7.9

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete
>   object type that is not a variable length array type.

You need to use compile time constant expressions as array dimensions to be able to use brace enclosed initializers.

You can use `#define` MACROs for this, like

```
#define ROW 2  //compile time constant expression
#define COL 2  //compile time constant expression

int mat1[ROW][COL]=
{
    {1,5},
    {4,6}
};
```

Comment: Baaam. It worked. that means i need to make the variable as final in MACROs.

Comment: @Enam It has to be compile time contants, that's all.

Comment: But i need to initialize the size of array at run time.now how can i do that so???

Comment: @Enam You need to understand, initialization happens in the compile time, you cannot have a VLA, (which determines the size at run time) to be initialized at compile time. Maybe you need pointers and memory allocator functions for that.

Answer (score 5):

What you have here is a variable length array.  Such an array cannot be initialized.  You can only initialize an array if the dimensions are constants (i.e. numeric constants, not variables declared as `const`):

```
int mat1[2][2]=
{
    {1,5},
    {4,6}
};
```

Comment: Quite so, but I suspect that the OP does not appreciate the distinction between integer literals and integer constants expressed via macros.  Absent that understanding, this answer would appear to be over-restrictive.

Comment: With a fixed initializer, what do macros for the dimensions buy you except the risk for bugs when changing them?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Not much, especially with multidimensional arrays, but if you want zeros at the end it can make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize a **variable-sized object**. You could try assigning the values later somewhere else or simply use numbers instead of variables.